# My Nokia Lumia-925 unable to connect with my office Wifi

Tags: wifi, lumia-925

My phone Nokia Lumia-925 unable to connect to my office Wifi since yesterday!!!
It appeared the message: 
" Can't connect.
  Your phone can't connect to the Wifi network xxxxxx".
even it can sense my office Wifi, my other colleagues's phone no problem with my office Wifi.
And there's nothing wrong with the Wifi password,

But my phone can automatically connected with my home Wifi and restaurants Wifi network.

So what wrong with this? And how to solve this?

Thank you very much.

David

Comment: Have you spoken with your office's local, friendly IT team in case they know the cause?